# Printing text at a particular position on pre printed paper form using C#

Tags: c#, printing

I need to print as in printing paper texts at a particular position of the print paper. The reason is that the printing is done on already printed form with fields such as first and last names. So when I get the name of the person and it should print within that allocated space in paper form.

Wondering if there are any exisiting libraries that will allow me to print at a particular position using a coordinate system like X and Y coordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something to get you started.......
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287530(v=vs.71).aspx

Using that tutorial, I would suggest you print roughly at the four corners of a page, that way you know the printing coordinate system.

Using that, and a good ol' ruler, you can figure out where the fields on your paper form are, and translate them to x-y coordinates on the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try making a PDF the same size as the form page, with the text appropriately positioned on it. Then print the PDF to the printer that has your pre-printed forms loaded in the paper try.

I'll leave it up to you to find a library that can work with PDFs. On Python I'd use `reportlab`. Find your local C# equivalent.

Comment: Note: I actually had to *do* this for a project once-upon-a-time. It works well, but remember to turn off the "scale to fit page" option when you print.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a C# form and add a print function from that you can manually set x and y coordinates at which your text will be printed on the form.

> Just edit new Point(x,y)

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Rangoli Travels", new Font("Arial",12,FontStyle.Regular),Brushes.Black, new Point(10,10);
    }
```