# Format Print Document in C#

Tags: c#, printing

I'm quite new to c# and need some help with formating a document for printing.

I already managed to talk to the printer via this code:

```
private void Print(string printer)
    {
        PrintDocument PrintDoc = new PrintDocument();

        PrintDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer;

        PrintDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
        PrintDoc.Print();
    }

    void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), new Point(0, 0), new Point(100, 100));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World", new Font("Times New Roman", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Point(45, 45));

    }
```

Which prints me my "hello world" string. Obviously the PrintPage method is code I found on the net.
Sadly I couldn't find a way to

a) set the format the size of the paper I print on (it is 138mm x 99mm landscape format)

b) tell the printer where to print my texts exactly.

The paper is a preprinted form and I have to write my text in the specific fields.

So I'm looking for a way to give my printer a formated document like:

```
<field1>
    <x> 2cm </x>
    <y> 1cm </y>
    <text> textfield1 </text>
</field1>
<field2>
     ....
```

I couldn't find information on how to do that. So if anyone could tell me how to do this or has a link to a good tutorial, I'd be very thankfull

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the size of the paper

```
printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom Name", width, height);
printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
```

**width and height is in hundredths of an inch**

See the tutorial in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612130/printing-text-at-a-particular-position-on-pre-printed-paper-form-using-c-sharp) SO question for printing text on pre-printed paper.

Also to avoid paper wastage during your experimentation, scan the preprinted paper as image and set it as background in `PrintPageHanlder` during preview.

```
void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    if (printDocument.PrintController.IsPreview)
    {
        Image image = Image.FromFile("ScannedImagePath");
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image,0,0)
    }
    // print other text here after drawing the background
}
```

Comment: I'd love to upvote your post, sadly I just registered and so don't have enough reputation to upvote your comment. I'm missing 4 points it seems ^^;

Comment: I finally have enough poits for upvoting. So better late than never I guess :)